# Java Generics vs Type in functions

Tags: java, generics

I read much about Generics recently.

```
public static <T extends CharSequence> void prnt(T obj);

public static void prnt(CharSequence obj);
```

Is there any difference between both ?

Comment: If you write the two methods, compile them, and then view the bytecote with javap, you can see for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

For your example it does not really make a difference.

Where it makes a difference is the following example:

```
    public static CharSequence foo1(CharSequence c) {...}

    public static <T extends CharSequence> T foo2(T t) {...}
```

Both will return an object that is a subtype of `CharSequence` but the second one allows more flexibility. Imagine the following code:

```
    String s = "test";
    CharSequence c = s;

    CharSequence c1 = foo1(c);
    CharSequence c2 = foo2(c);
```

This works fine just as you expect.

```
    CharSequence c1 = foo1(s);
    String s2 = foo2(s);
```

Here we see why it might make sense to declare the function using generics. With `<T extends CharSequence>` we can enforce that the function only works with subclasses of `CharSequence` without losing the information about the actual type. The first method on the other hand will lose this information and maybe even force you to have a cast which is really ugly.

Answer (score -1):

*IN your case they're equal*, 
They both work on something that implements CharSequence.

**In the general case they're not equal at all!**

For instance imagine to return T in the first case and CharSequence in the second as follows:

```
public static <T extends CharSequence> T prnt(T obj);

public static CharSequence prnt(CharSequence obj);
```

Let's use both with CharBuffer (that implements CharSequence)

```
public static CharBuffer prnt(CharBuffer obj);

public static CharSequence prnt(CharSequence obj);
```

As you see they're not equal at all.